# Why is my proportion estimate 0? (BEST MCMC Bayesian inference)

Tags: r, inference, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to run a simple Bayesian inference on my y1 vector as shown below.

```r
library(BEST)

y1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)

mc <- BESTmcmc(y1, parallel = TRUE)

plotAll(mc)
```

I tried playing with the priors and other parameters of the BESTmcmc function but I seem to always get a 95% HDI centered at 0, when really I expect it to be centered at 0.2 (the mean of my y1 vector). This still happens even though I set my muM prior at 0.2.

Does anyone know how I can correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The BEST package is an alternative to a t-test.  Your likelihood is a Bernoulli likelihood, not a normal one.  From reviewing the documentation, it appears it is not a correct package for what you are trying to do.

On the surface, it appears that it should work as an approximation, but you do not provide your priors and I have a guess as to what may be happening.  As a note, that is not a package that I use, but I am guessing from the documentation.

The binomial, which is the multi-observation version of the Bernoulli, has only one parameter, the proportion.  Student's t-distribution has more than one parameter.  Have you specified a prior distribution for your variance?  It may be of zero width if you have not specified it.  Since it has been standardized to be around a 0 mean, then a standardized t-distribution with a prior variance of zero is zero.  Remember, the goal of this is to replace the t-test and it is not to find the location of the parameters.  Some of this is a guess because there is no other code provided.

If you used a Haldane prior and a Bernoulli likelihood, then your 95% credible interval would be bounded between .0281 and .482.  With a uniform prior it would be bounded between .0602 and .518. That should give you a guess as to where your 95% credible interval should sit with an uninformative prior.

Take a look at your priors and remember, this is not an estimator of the proportion but of a normal mean and prior that has been standardized to replace the t-test.